# How can I configure the swagger ui page for Azure Functions v3?

Tags: azure-functions, openapi, openapi-generator

I added OpenApi support to an Azure functions application (v3), using `.ConfigureOpenApi()` in `Program.Main()`.  I use function decorations for the specific functions but how can I control the general API name, version etc, shown on ~/api/swagger/ui ?

Here is my `Program.Main()` code:

```
        public static void Main()
        {

            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(worker => worker.UseNewtonsoftJson())        
                .ConfigureOpenApi()
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                    {
                        services.AddLogging();
                    }
                )
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to include the API metadata like API Name, version?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To control the API meta-information you should define a class that implements `IOpenApiConfigurationOptions` (located in namespace `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Abstractions`).

*Note: There should be only one implementation of the `IOpenApiConfigurationOptions` interface in your project. Class namespace or visibility does not seem to matter.*

The easiest way to do it is to inherit `DefaultOpenApiConfigurationOptions` provided by `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core` and override specific properties.

Add a file to your project with the following content (and update necessary values):

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Configurations;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Enums;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

namespace MyApp
{
    internal class OpenApiConfigurationOptions : DefaultOpenApiConfigurationOptions
    {
        public override OpenApiInfo Info { get; set; } = new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Version = "1.0.0",
            Title = "My API",
            Description = "My API description",
            License = new OpenApiLicense
            {
                Name = "MIT",
                Url = new Uri("http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"),
            }
        };

        public override OpenApiVersionType OpenApiVersion { get; set; } = OpenApiVersionType.V3;
    }
}
```

There are sample projects from Microsoft that can be [found here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/blob/main/samples)

Comment: The hyperlink to the sample code is broken, due to a refactoring in that GitHub repo on February 11, 2022. I don't know how the new folder structure fits this post. Any suggestions?