# OpenApiExample not showing up in swagger UI

Tags: azure-functions, swagger-ui, openapi

I have a new .NET6 Azure Functions application. I created a few HTTP functions with OpenAPI specifications.
My swagger page is working fine, except for the POST function.
I would like to show a minimal body request on this page as an example.
I've implemented `IOpenApiExample` as mentioned at https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/blob/main/docs/openapi-core.md#openapirequestbodyattribute
but the example is not used. It keeps showing the whole model without any sample values.

This is my relevant code:

```cs
    [FunctionName("PostHistoryEvent")]
    [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "PostHistoryEvent", tags: new[] { "Post HistoryEvent" })]
    [OpenApiSecurity("function_key", SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, Name = "code", In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Query)]
    [OpenApiRequestBody("application/json", typeof(HistoryEvent), Required = true, Description = "Description of OpenApiRequestBody", Example = typeof(HistoryEventOpenApiExample))]
    [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.Created, contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(HistoryEvent), Description = "The created History Event")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostHistoryEvent(...){...}


    public class HistoryEventOpenApiExample : OpenApiExample<HistoryEvent>
    {        
        public override IOpenApiExample<HistoryEvent> Build(NamingStrategy namingStrategy = null)
        {
            Examples.Add(OpenApiExampleResolver.Resolve(
                "first",
                new HistoryEvent()
                {
                    ObjectId = "foo",
                    More properties ...
                },
                namingStrategy));
            return this;
        }
    }
```

I assume I need to do add something, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you don't see examples in Swagger UI is likely that your Azure function is using OpenAPI 2.0 specification (aka Swagger 2.0). Setting `OpenApiRequestBodyAttribute.Example` will only affect OpenAPI 3. For some reason, by default, Azure Functions OpenAPI Extension library [is using OpenAPI 2.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/blob/4e81588f399f642236e354f00f64de99dccb859a/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core/Configurations/DefaultOpenApiConfigurationOptions.cs#L156-L159).

There are two ways you can fix this.

#### Option 1. Switch to OpenAPI 3 using `OpenApiConfigurationOptions`

If you already have a `OpenApiConfigurationOptions` implementation class, then update `OpenApiVersion` value to `OpenApiVersionType.V3`. Otherwise, [just create one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69543038/8607180).

It should look something like this:

```cs
    public class OpenApiConfigurationOptions : DefaultOpenApiConfigurationOptions
    {
        public override OpenApiVersionType OpenApiVersion { get; set; } = OpenApiVersionType.V3;

        // you can also update your API info as well here
        // public override OpenApiInfo Info { get; set; } = new OpenApiInfo { ... };
    }
```

#### Option 2. (if you want to keep using OpenAPI 2.0) Use the `OpenApiExample` attribute on a model

Add the `OpenApiExample` attribute to your data model that has a link to your `HistoryEventOpenApiExample` class.

```cs
    [OpenApiExample(typeof(HistoryEventOpenApiExample))]
    public class HistoryEvent
    {
        public string ObjectId { get; set; }
        // More properties ...
    }
```

#### References

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/issues/106

Comment: I implemented option 1 and now it is working as expected. I'll mark your post as the answer.